# Generate project-scratch-def automatically (in absence of Org Shape)

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, shape-org

We are implementing CI/CD for our projects and would like to automatically generate the `project-scratch-def.json` file for each project. Given the fact that the Org Shape feature is still in pilot, what is the next-best possible solution that you have encountered that can speed up the generation of the definition file?

The SFSE post [How should I configure project-scratch-def.json to match my production/scratch org?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209651/how-should-i-configure-project-scratch-def-json-to-match-my-production-scratch-o) reiterates my questions pretty well, however it's about 2 years old and given the many SFDX plugins that have been created since 2018 I am wondering if the landscape has changed.

Comment: The `settings` element of the scratch definition is 1:1 with Metadata Api settings entities; one could pull those entities and script conversion to the SFDX format. The Features keys, I don't see a straightforward solution for - likely a lot of work to do inference. Curious to see if there are better proposals.